# Почему после фильтрации в стриме выводится пустое поле

Tags: java, потоки-данных

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle vh1 = new Vehicle("Audi A7",'g',300,2012,5.4);
        Vehicle vh2 = new Vehicle("MB CLS",'g',545,2016,5.2);
        Vehicle vh3 = new Vehicle("Tesla",'e',345,2018,4.5);
        Vehicle vh4 = new Vehicle("VW Golf",'g',245,2021,6.4);
        Vehicle vh5 = new Vehicle("LR Range Rover",'d',339,2019,6.9);
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        vehicles.add(vh1);
        vehicles.add(vh2);
        vehicles.add(vh3);
        vehicles.add(vh4);
        vehicles.add(vh5);
        vehicles = vehicles.stream().filter(element -> element.getTypeEngine()>290&&element.getZeroToOneHundred()<6).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(vehicles);
    }
}

class Vehicle{
    private String model;
    private char typeEngine;
    private int horsePower;
    private int releaseYear;
    private double zeroToOneHundred;

    public Vehicle(String model, char typeEngine, int horsePower, int releaseYear, double zeroToOneHundred) {
        this.model = model;
        this.typeEngine = typeEngine;
        this.horsePower = horsePower;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.zeroToOneHundred = zeroToOneHundred;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vehicle{" +
                "model='" + model + '\'' +
                ", typeEngine=" + typeEngine +
                ", horsePower=" + horsePower +
                ", releaseYear=" + releaseYear +
                ", zeroToOneHundred=" + zeroToOneHundred +
                '}';
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public char getTypeEngine() {
        return typeEngine;
    }

    public void setTypeEngine(char typeEngine) {
        this.typeEngine = typeEngine;
    }

    public int getHorsePower() {
        return horsePower;
    }

    public void setHorsePower(int horsePower) {
        this.horsePower = horsePower;
    }

    public int getReleaseYear() {
        return releaseYear;
    }

    public void setReleaseYear(int releaseYear) {
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    }

    public double getZeroToOneHundred() {
        return zeroToOneHundred;
    }

    public void setZeroToOneHundred(double zeroToOneHundred) {
        this.zeroToOneHundred = zeroToOneHundred;
    }
}
```

после запуска выводится "[]", но должно выводить ауди и теслу. можете подсказать в каком направлении думать? я никак не разгляжу, что я упустил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ни один объект не подходит по критерию getTypeEngine()>290. У вас элементы:

```
g=103
e=101
d=100
```

ЛЮБОЙ из них меньше 290 из вашего Predicate в методе фильтр, соответственно они все отрабрсываются и до проверки **getZeroToOneHundred**  дело даже не доходит. Вероятно вы имели ввиду лошадиные силы вместо типа двигателя?

```
public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle vh1 = new Vehicle("Audi A7",'g',300,2012,5.4);
        Vehicle vh2 = new Vehicle("MB CLS",'g',545,2016,5.2);
        Vehicle vh3 = new Vehicle("Tesla",'e',345,2018,4.5);
        Vehicle vh4 = new Vehicle("VW Golf",'g',245,2021,6.4);
        Vehicle vh5 = new Vehicle("LR Range Rover",'d',339,2019,6.9);
        List<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<>();
        vehicles.add(vh1);
        vehicles.add(vh2);
        vehicles.add(vh3);
        vehicles.add(vh4);
        vehicles.add(vh5);
        vehicles = vehicles.stream().filter(element -> element.getHorsePower()>290&&element.getZeroToOneHundred()<6).collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(vehicles);
    }
}
```

Выход:

```
[Vehicle{model='Audi A7', typeEngine=g, horsePower=300, releaseYear=2012, zeroToOneHundred=5.4}, Vehicle{model='MB CLS', typeEngine=g, horsePower=545, releaseYear=2016, zeroToOneHundred=5.2}, Vehicle{model='Tesla', typeEngine=e, horsePower=345, releaseYear=2018, zeroToOneHundred=4.5}]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: спасибо большое, только щас заметил наиглупейшую ошибку